# The right way of memory management

Tags: c++, memory-management

```
class Word
{
private:
    std::string w;
public:
    Word(std::string w) : w(w) {}
};

class Sentence
{
private:
    std::list<Word *> words;

public:        
    Sentence(std::list<Word *> words) : words(words) {}

    ~Sentence() {
        for (auto word : words)
            delete word;
        words.clear();
    }
};

int main() {
    Word *word1 = new Word("abc");
    Word *word2 = new Word("def");
    Sentence sentence1( std::list<Word *>({word1, word2}) );
    Sentence sentence2 = sentence1;
    return 0;
}
```

(actual classes are bigger; I really need to use pointers to `Word`, allocated in other function)
Objects `word1` and `word2` will be deleted twice. I have these options for solving the problem:

1. Add methods `Word * Word::clone(const Word *word)` and `Sentence * Sentence::clone(const Sentence *s)` and call them in `Sencence::operator=`. But in this case my program uses too much memory (words in sentences are the same, but allocated in memory twice).
2. Use smart pointers. Then my program becomes a bit less efficient (and the code becomes more complicated).
3. Add `bool isCopy` to `Sentence` and delete words only if `isCopy == false`. It looks stupid, I think.

So what should I do better?

Comment: What do you need? Will the sentences *conceptually* contain different copies of the same word or not? In the former case, don't use pointers at all, and pass everything by value. In the latter case, I would strongly suggest allocating the words in a scope that outlives the sentences, storing them in unique_ptr's, and just pass them by reference or non-owning raw pointer. But I don't know what kind of behaviour you want so I can't answer the question.

Comment: Are you modifying the words themselves? Then you need a copy. Otherwise use a (wrapped) `shared_ptr<const word>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shared_ptr<Word>`. Not because it's the fastest, because that's what you mean conceptually. And it's proven right. Only start this low level of optimization when you're sure it's slow compared to the program (hint: it's not).

<1.> means you don't share the instances, which you conceptually might want to. What if you change one of the words?

<3.> means you're not thread-safe. Okay, you add a mutex - then you'll end up implementing a DIY `shared_ptr<>` that you'll have to support, that'll most probably be slower/more error-prone (think about the number of users - testers! - of the official one). Not worth the effort.

Comment: Downvoter: could you please comment on how I could improve this answer / what you find wrong in it?

Comment: I wouldn't take the odd down vote to heart. There are all kinds of reasons that people might not like the answer. If you get more than 2 with no upvotes, then it's probably a signal that you've missed something. I think you;ve answered the question so I'll give you +1 :)

Comment: @RichardHodges: exactly that's why I've asked. If I've missed something, I'd like to learn as well :) - that's the main benefit here for me. Also I want others to find proper answers here, like I tend to do when I'm searching for something. Hence I've asked - I don't mind critics when it improves me and the world around me.

Answer (score 2):

Never use collections of pointers to anything. If you must have a heap-allocated implementation of word, wrap it in a handle class that has value-like behaviour.

Then store it in the list (or vector, etc)

e.g:

```
struct word_impl {};   // big thing

auto clone(const word_impl& impl) -> std::unique_ptr<word_impl> {
    // clone could if you wished, defer to a virtual clone method
    // on word_impl
    return std::make_unique<word_impl>(impl);
}


struct word
{
     // construct from letters
     word(const char* letters) : impl_ { std::make_unique<word_impl>(letters) } { }

     // let's make it copyable
     word(const word& r) : impl_ { clone(r.impl_) } {}

     word& operator=(const word& r) {
         if (this != std::addressof(r)) {
             impl_ = clone(r.impl_);
         }
         return *this;
     }  

     // and moveable
     word(word&& r) = default;
     word& operator=(word&& r) = default;

private:

     std::unique_ptr<word_impl> impl_;
}
```

Here's a complete, compilable example that expresses the word object in terms of both shared and cloneable words.

What I have tried to do here is separate the concerns of "sharedness" and the actual operations on words.

This allows you to have a sentence of unique words or shared words, using the same code at the client site. The user needs no knowledge of the internal workings of a word, or even how its memory is managed. All he needs to know is that it can be copied, printed and compared (in this case).

There is also a further operation to convert a unique_word into a shared_word.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/operators.hpp>

//
// define some protocols that a handle class can inherit from. These
// translate methods on the handle onto methods on the implementation
//
template<class Handle>
struct implement_ostream_protocol {
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const implement_ostream_protocol &proto) {
        auto &ref = static_cast<const Handle &>(proto).get_reference();
        return os << ref;
    }
};

template<class Handle, class Comp = std::less<>>
struct implement_less_than_protocol {
    friend bool operator<(const implement_less_than_protocol &l, const implement_less_than_protocol &r) {
        auto &lr = static_cast<const Handle &>(l).get_reference();
        auto &rr = static_cast<const Handle &>(r).get_reference();
        auto comp = Comp();
        return comp(lr, rr);
    }
};

template<class Handle>
struct implement_setValue_protocol {
    template<class T>
    decltype(auto) setValue(T&& value)
    {
        auto &lr = static_cast<Handle &>(*this).get_reference();
        return lr.setValue(std::forward<T>(value));
    }
};

//
// this is the implementation of a word
//
struct word_impl {
    word_impl(const char *letters) : word_(letters) {
        std::cout << "constructed word: " << word_ << std::endl;
    }

    word_impl(const word_impl &r) : word_(r.word_) {
        std::cout << "copied word: " << word_ << std::endl;
    }

    word_impl(word_impl &&r) noexcept : word_(std::move(r.word_)) {
        std::cout << "moved word: " << word_ << std::endl;
    }

    word_impl &operator=(const word_impl &r) {
        if (this != std::addressof(r)) {
            word_ = r.word_;
            std::cout << "assigned word: " << word_ << std::endl;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    word_impl &operator=(word_impl &&r) noexcept {
        if (this != std::addressof(r)) {
            word_ = std::move(r.word_);
            std::cout << "move-assigned word: " << word_ << std::endl;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    // some wordy operations
    bool comes_before(const word_impl &r) const {
        return word_ < r.word_;
    }

    void setValue(const char* p)
    {
        std::cout << "value changed from " << word_ << " to " << p << "\n";
        word_ = p;
    }

    // write myself
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const word_impl &r) {
        return os << std::quoted(r.word_);
    }

    struct comes_before_op {
        bool operator()(const word_impl &l, const word_impl &r) const {
            return l.word_ < r.word_;
        }
    };

    std::string word_;
};   // big thing

//
// these are the protocols I want all types of word handles to support
//
template<class Handle>
struct word_impl_protocols
        : implement_ostream_protocol<Handle>,
          implement_less_than_protocol<Handle, word_impl::comes_before_op> ,
          implement_setValue_protocol<Handle>,
          boost::less_than_comparable<word_impl_protocols<Handle>>
{

};


auto clone(const word_impl &impl) -> std::unique_ptr<word_impl> {
    // clone could if you wished, defer to a virtual clone method
    // on word_impl
    return std::make_unique<word_impl>(impl);
}


//
// lets make a copyable word that clones its implementation
//
struct unique_word
        : word_impl_protocols<unique_word> {
    // construct from letters
    unique_word(const char *letters) : impl_{std::make_unique<word_impl>(letters)} {}

    // let's make it copyable
    unique_word(const unique_word &r) : impl_{clone(*r.impl_)} {}

    unique_word &operator=(const unique_word &r) {
        if (this != std::addressof(r)) {
            impl_ = clone(*r.impl_);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    // and moveable
    unique_word(unique_word &&r) noexcept = default;

    unique_word &operator=(unique_word &&r) noexcept = default;

    word_impl const &get_reference() const {
        return *impl_;
    }

    word_impl &get_reference() {
        return *impl_;
    }

    // warning - destructive - provides a means to create a
    // shared word from a unique_word
    auto share() {
        return std::shared_ptr<word_impl> {std::move(impl_)};
    }

private:

    std::unique_ptr<word_impl> impl_;
};

//
// and a word type that shares its implementation
//
struct shared_word
        : word_impl_protocols<shared_word> {
    shared_word(const char *letters) : impl_{std::make_shared<word_impl>(letters)} {}

    shared_word(unique_word &&source) : impl_{source.share()} {}

    const word_impl &get_reference() const { return *impl_; }
    word_impl &get_reference() { return *impl_; }

    std::shared_ptr<word_impl> impl_;
};


int main() {

    std::cout << "creating first sentence:\n";
    std::vector<unique_word> sentence1 = [] {
        std::vector<unique_word> result;
        result.emplace_back("abc");
        result.emplace_back("def");
        result.emplace_back("ghi");
        return result;
    }();

    std::cout << "copying first sentence:\n";
    std::vector<unique_word> sentence2 = sentence1;
    std::sort(sentence2.begin(), sentence2.end(), std::greater<>());

    std::copy(sentence1.begin(), sentence1.end(), std::ostream_iterator<unique_word>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::copy(sentence2.begin(), sentence2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<unique_word>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "converting first sentence to shared words:\n";
    std::vector<shared_word> sentence3;
    for (auto& unique : sentence1)
    {
        sentence3.emplace_back(std::move(unique));
    }
    std::copy(sentence3.begin(), sentence3.end(), std::ostream_iterator<shared_word>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "copying sentence of shared words:\n";
    auto sentence4 = sentence3;

    std::cout << "changing the first word of a shared word sentence:\n";
    sentence3.at(0).setValue("xyz");
    std::copy(sentence3.begin(), sentence3.end(), std::ostream_iterator<shared_word>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::copy(sentence4.begin(), sentence4.end(), std::ostream_iterator<shared_word>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

expected output:

```
creating first sentence:
constructed word: abc
constructed word: def
constructed word: ghi
copying first sentence:
copied word: abc
copied word: def
copied word: ghi
"abc", "def", "ghi", 
"ghi", "def", "abc", 
converting first sentence to shared words:
"abc", "def", "ghi", 
copying sentence of shared words:
changing the first word of a shared word sentence:
value changed from abc to xyz
"xyz", "def", "ghi", 
"xyz", "def", "ghi",
```

Comment: Can you pls explain why? I mean, why not container of pointers and why force a wrapper on the user instead of giving the flexibility to choose whether to keep ptr or value? (And why write a wrapper for every class, that seems an overhead.)

Comment: @loro values are easier to reason about than pointers. Particularly in containers, where you very often want the concepts of lifetime and comparison taken care of. In your case you mentioned clone. It's kinder on the users to give them normal copy semantics than to force knowledge of the clone protocol on them. You may in future choose to change how the cloning works. It would be a shame to force changes to all user code as a result.

Comment: but how can you be sure that OP expects value schematics? What if OP wants to build a trivial spell checker (which replaces incorrect words with correct ones)? Note that the `string` in `word` is mutable - if I assign the same word to two sentences and change the word itself, I expected both to be changed.

Comment: @lorro in that case you would implement the word class in terms of a shared_ptr rather than a unique_ptr and remove the copy/move code as it's not needed.

Comment: @lorro I've updated the example. I have provided an implementation of a word object plus two handles that allow either shared or unique (clonable) ownership of the word. So the user of the word class can choose whether he wants unique or shared behaviour. Either way he's able to deal with the words as values rather than pointers. Yes it seems more complicated than maybe required, but most of this code is boilerplate that can be libraryfied (something I intend to do before too long).

Comment: I see now your idea on `implement_XXX_protocol<>` very useful. If I see it correctly, `shared_word/unique_word` is a custom pointer (which might even be specializations of a `shared<T> / unique<T>` _if_ there are common protocols). Actually, adding `friend bool operator<(const shared_word&, const unique_word&)` can give you sg you don't directly have w/ std ptrs (w/o deref): underlying comparison amongst different ptr types. Nice way of implementing a common protocol.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Solution with smart pointers looks good if you don't want to change words in each copy of Sentence independently.

Solution with deep copy is also good it it's what you want i.e. you want separate copy of each word (so you can change them independently). However you should consider using a copy constructor for this (or at least delete it).

Solution with bool looks really bad for me, since it implies that the first instance must be destroyed after it's copies. However if you replace the bool with some shared refcounter (std::shared_ptr) it would be also acceptable but only under the assumption that these objects are totally immutable after creation.